# Regular expression to match string not containing other substring

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression to match a string that does not include specific substrings
For example I need to get all strings `/<abc.*>/` except of `/<abcD.*>/` and `/<abcE.*>/`

Comment: Could you show a real example and add a tag for the programming language or tool you use?

Comment: Try this [`/<abc(?:[^DE].*|[^DE]*)>/`](https://regex101.com/r/1KezUg/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should be like:

```
/<abc(?![DE]).*>/
```

or if you have longer undesirable string:

```
/<abc(?!(?:D|E|otherUndesirableString)).*/
```